# IP version in synthetic monitoring context?

Tags: monitoring, ipv6

I am trying to setup monitoring on my website and I have encountered with this option IPv4/ IPv6.

What could it mean in this context ?
[image: see the screenshoot]

Comment: Sorry, are you asking us what ipv4 and ipv6 are?

Answer (score 2):

It is asking you whether you want it to monitor IPv4 or IPv6 connectivity to the service.

For optimal reliability modern clients will automatically try both IPv4 and IPv6 such that the service will appear to be working just fine as long as either works.

That does mean that you cannot rely on reports from users to detect connectivity problems (which would have been a flawed approach to monitoring in the first place). Instead you need to have monitoring that can tell you right away if either of the two protocols is inaccessible at the moment.

The proper answer to the question would be that you want it to monitor both. Depending on the monitoring service you are using it may be possible to create a single monitor for both, or it may be necessary to create two separate monitors for IPv4 and IPv6 respectively.

Comment: In case it is of any relevance, I could mention that Google is publishing [daily statistics on IPv6 usage](http://www.google.com/intl/en/ipv6/statistics.html). Tomorrow is probably going to be the first day ever that Google see more than 10% of IPv6.